# Can elasticsearch magically filters fields while matching a tittle?

Tags: elasticsearch

The question is simple, when a user search for `a red fox`, I want to match the title for `fox`, and also I want to filter the color by `red`, because a color appears in the search term and the title field may not contain the keyword `red`.

So is there a way to achieve this within elasticsearch, or do I have to get the tokenized phrase first and then construct the query in application level?

Many thanks.

--- Edit ---

Can elasticsearch magically identify a keyword and filter a specific field, rather than filtering by all the tokenized keywords?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know it is not possible to do this entity recognize (in your case finding color name) in Elasticsearch OOTB. You can use application level or third party library for same outside elasticsearch.

Also, 8.x version support entity extraction with third party model and you can deploy model in Elasticsearch itself. You can read my medium blog [here](https://medium.com/@psajan106/elasticsearch-8-named-entity-recognition-ner-using-inference-ingest-pipeline-8e7bd566c5e8) on same topic.

Comment: I have read your post, but I'm not familiar with AI yet, and it seems a bit overkilled to me. I thought maybe there's a ruleset I can use to map a keyword to a field. Well, if there are no OOTB solutions, I have to implement it at application level. Appreciate the answer. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you can apply rule base or dictionory base extraction as well but make sure that it will not impact the query response time.

Answer (score 0):

What I was originally trying to achieve is:

When I search for something, I actually want to filter them. For example, if I search for `a red fox`, I want to filter out something which the color is `red`, and which the name is `fox`.

I was thinking in the wrong way.

I should define a join field, containing the color and the name. Then perform the query on that field.

For example, define a field named `title` containing `red fox`. Then when I search for `a red fox`, the matched record would come up.

```json
PUT /animals
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "copy_to": "title" 
      },
      "color": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "copy_to": "title" 
      },
      "title": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This solved my problem.